# Why is my Rack app hanging?

Tags: ruby, streaming, rack

I've written an open source Rack app and core lirary to stream stock quotes from Tradeking.com. Here's the rack app: https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_websocket_service. And here's the core library: https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_core.

I modified trading_core/lib/trading_core/quote_streamer/tradeking.rb to output streamed data to the console, as so:

```
@http.stream do |data|
  puts data
```

After a few hours of it streaming and outputting to the console, it simply freezes. I have absolutely no idea why. I've done my best to ensure that any loops are not infinite. I've been debugging this for over a week now.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here are the main files where I think this could be happening:

- https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_core/blob/master/lib/trading_core/client_data_broker.rb
- https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_core/blob/master/lib/trading_core/quote_streamer/tradeking.rb
- https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_websocket_service/blob/master/lib/web_socket_service.rb

Comment: You might need to make sure you close the connection: @http.close in an ensure block at the end of the method you referenced

Comment: Didn't seem to help :(

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to dig into the ruby process you're running to figure out what's choking it up. Depending on what OS you're on of course, on mac and linux you can use tools like gdb, strace, dtrace, etc. For example: http://ruby.dzone.com/articles/debugging-stuck-ruby-processes

Comment: Here's what I see when I run strace: http://chadjohnson.io/strace.png

Comment: Looks like its running the select command a lot. This system call is used to wait for activity at the provided file descriptors. these could be the sockets EventMachine is using to communicate with the tradking service. Does this service do any rate limiting?

Comment: Rate limiting, as in bandwidth? Or a timeout? Not sure. So, does this mean my client might continue trying to talk to Tradeking, but Tradeking is refusing to respond? If I kill the process and restart rackup, things work again immediately.

Comment: Okay, Tradeking support tells me no rate limits are implemented besides a limit of 256 symbols (I'm streaming 10).

Comment: My only hunch that still holds is that you're creating a lot of connections and not closing them, and the processing is lagging because of it. Can't help you much more unfortunately. Do some more digging to try to make your next help question more specific.

Comment: Could you run `lsof -p <PID>`, once after 1 minute, once as soon as it's stuck? In case Mac doesn't have that: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-list-of-open-files/

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I believe we've solved the problem! Your idea about creating a lot of connections and not closing them was close, and it gave me the lead I needed. It seems the change that made the difference was here, in trading_api/tradeking.rb: https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_core/commit/8444faec00b86e5c7dd7c1d0eab5a0587d0a1435. Basically, I was caching a connection to the Tradeking API via `@api ||= begin`, and so a dead API connection was being reused when API requests were made and the connection died. So, feel free to answer this question, and I will award you the bounty!

Comment: Awesome thanks for coming back and posting your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad I could push you in the right direction!

My first hunches were about open connections:

> You might need to make sure you close the connection: @http.close in
>   an ensure block at the end of the method you referenced

Then on to some forensics:

> Sounds like you'll have to dig into the ruby process you're running to
>   figure out what's choking it up. Depending on what OS you're on of
>   course, on mac and linux you can use tools like gdb, strace, dtrace,
>   etc. For example:
>   ruby.dzone.com/articles/debugging-stuck-ruby-processes

We found that `select` was being called a lot which led us to keep our suspicion on the connections. **Turns out the problem was in reusing a dead connection via `@api ||= ...init code...`**

Glad you were able to find what it was! And thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 1):

On the first look at your code I could imagine two reasons for your issues:

1. You are hitting rate limits with Tradeking (maybe using more than 256 symbols or multiple instances of your script (they don't like that) or updating your symbols too fast (changing them)
2. As you are parsing every incoming message you might "choke" your stream. I see that a lot with people using Twitter streams, parsing the results and writing them to a DB. It's just too slow and then starts blocking.

Comment: Good thoughts, and thank you for your feedback. I believe I've solved the problem, and it does not seem this was this issue. But, if the issue presents itself again, I will definitely take your second idea under consideration.